# Order By In Subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery, sql-order-by

HOW TO GET SUBQUERY DATA ASEC ORDER IN ORACLE DB. BECAUSE IN SUBQUERY ORDER BY IS NOT WORKING

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(

'jobId' VALUE a.job_id,

'change_order' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT(

'jobId' VALUE JOB_ID,

'changeNbr' VALUE CHANGE_NBR,

'changeDesc' VALUE CHANGE_DESC,

'status' VALUE CHANGE_STATUS

RETURNING CLOB)

RETURNING CLOB)

from builder_change_order_view

where job_id =${jobId}

AND rownum < 4

ORDER BY change_nbr )

),
```

This is the sample output,
actually, I want an array in an object in ascending order {"change_number":1, "qwerty":[{"samp1": "test1"},{"samp2": "test2"},{"samp3": "test3"}]}.
ie, array values in ascending order({"":"", array:[1,2,3,5]})

Comment: Please do not shout on us

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: Thanks for the replay, this is sample output, actually, I want an array in an object in asnc order

{"change_number":1,"qwerty":[{"samp1":"test1"},{"samp2":"test2"},{"samp3":"test3"}]}

Comment: Please add these information to your question

Comment: Use `order by` clause of [`json_arrayagg`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `JSON_ARRAYAGG`'s own `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(...) ORDER BY change_nbr)
```

Note that your `ROWNUM` filtering doesn't work correctly this way. It filters by arbitrary `ROWNUM` *prior* to ordering, so if you just want to aggregate the top 3 values, you'll have to use a derived table for this:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_AGG(JSON_OBJECT(...) ORDER BY change_nbr)
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM builder_change_order_view
  WHERE job_id = ${jobId}
  ORDER BY change_nbr
  FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
) t
```